# How to get all parenthesis captures in a javascript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

If I do:

```
"A first sentence. A second sentence".match(/A\s([^\s]*)\ssentence/g)
```

this returns:

```
["A first sentence", "A second sentence"]
```

And if I use:

```
RegExp.$1
```

then I just get the last first parenthesis capture, so `"second"`.

I'd like to get the array `["first","second"]`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to run it in a loop, and build the collection.

```
var str = "A first sentence. A second sentence",
    regex = /A\s([^\s]*)\ssentence/g,
    result = [],
    match;

while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
    result.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Because the regex is `g` global, it remembers the position of the last match, and starts from there the next time the regex is used. So the loop will continue until no more matches are found.

Inside the loop, we just add the subgroup to the `result` Array.

---

Some people like to use `.replace` for this purpose.

```
var str = "A first sentence. A second sentence",
    regex = /A\s([^\s]*)\ssentence/g,
    result = [];

str.replace(regex, function(str, g1) {
    result.push(g1);
});

console.log(result);
```

We're not actually doing a string replacement, but rather are just taking advantage of the fact that it repeats the search until no more matches are found.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that there was a sort of iterator. The solution with replace could be pretty.

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, the `.replace()` can be handy. This is a little bit of an abuse since its intended purpose is to have the callback return a value to be used in the replace, but it's still convenient for cases like this.

Comment: It's possible to make an alias, like: String.prototype.matchAll = String.prototype.replace, for a better semantic.

Comment: @Gael: Yes, you could have it return an Array of matches of the first subgroup if you'd like: `String.prototype.matchAll = function(regex) { var result = []; this.replace(regex, function(str, g1) { result.push(g1); }); return result; };`

Comment: And with undefined number of captures:
 String.prototype.matchAll = function(regex){
  var results = []; 
  this.replace(regex, function() {
   var result = []
   for( var i = 1 ; i < arguments.length - 2 ; i++ )
    result.push( arguments[i] );
   results.push( result );
  });
  return results;
 };

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-run the regex without the `g` modifier to get the subpatterns. Something like:

```
"A first sentence. A second sentence".match(/A\s([^\s]*)\ssentence/g)
    .map(function(a) {return a.match(/A\s([^\s]*)\ssentence/);})
```

(Assuming `Array.prototype.map` is present or shimmed - use a loop otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, define

```
function runRegex(str, pat, ret){ 
  return str.match(pat).map(function(a){ 
    a.match(pat); var b; eval("with(RegExp) b = " + ret + ";"); return b;
  });
}
```

and use it with desired parameters

```
runRegex("A first sentence. A second sentence", /A\s([^\s]*)\ssentence/g, "$1");
```

Check [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PbvnC/).

---

The beauty of this solution is that you can use complex return formulas, such as

```
runRegex("A first sentence. A second sentence", /A\s([^\s]*)(\ssentence)/g, "$1+$2"));
```

Comment: It could be interesting to have the control of the return and the match.map is more "right" than replace (regarding to the solution of user1689607), but the eval could be avoid.

Comment: @Geal - My solution shows what is possible. Certainly, in your case, `eval` can be avoid easily: (1) remove `ret` parameter; (2) replace the body of the `function(a)` with `{ a.match(pat); return RegExp.$1; }`.